# Updating inactive screens conditionally react-native

Tags: react-native, state

I have this react-native application using AppNavigator handling navigation between screens. I have trouble updating the paused (AppNavigator calls these screens "Blurred") screens.

I would like to be able to update the inactive screens from an active one.

I tried to add a listener on app notifications or subscribing to specific changes in a mobx store that should update the component, however the screen component won't react when not active/focused.

How can I make sure the screens updates when not active? I am unsure if I am tackling this fundamentally wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In previous versions of `react-navigation` there was a way to disable `lazy loading` but that has been taken out in the newer versions.

What you are asking for will hinder you in the long term. It will basically keep all the screens loaded in the memory. You shouldn't need that just to update them. Instead you can update the `MobX` store and when the screen becomes active again look for the changes and update accordingly.

Use [NavigationEvents](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-events.html) to listen to when the screen becomes active.